# I do not understand why i get this error: [...] got multiple values for argument [...]

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I defined the following function:

```
def lattice_pipe(real_coords, guess_cmap): 
    guess_coords = laplacian_coords(guess_cmap)
    return fitness(real_coords, kabsch(real_coords,guess_coords))
```

And the i called it in this way:

```
fit = list(map(functools.partial(lattice_pipe, real_coords = coords_real, guess_cmap = cmap_guess), population))
```

But I get the following error:

> fit = list(map(functools.partial(lattice_pipe, real_coords =
>   coords_real, guess_cmap = cmap_guess), population))
>
> TypeError: lattice_pipe() got multiple values for argument
>   'real_coords'

I cannot understand why I am getting this because I think I am giving it only the two arguments it requires which are real_coords and guess_cmap...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `functools.partial()` is binding the `real_coords` argument to `coords_real`, but then you're passing the argument again when you use `map()`.

Comment: What argument do you want the elements of `population` to be used for?

Comment: I need to use the Guessed contact map (guess_cmap) of every individual in population

Comment: If you want to get that parameter from `population`, don't put it in the `functools.partial()` call.

Comment: BTW, `map` returns a list, so you don't need to call `list()`.

Comment: ookay thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the `guess_cmap` from `population`, don't bind it in the `functools.partial()` call. Use a list comprehension to extract it from each element.

```
fit = map(functools.partial(lattice_pipe, real_coords = coords_real), [p['guess_cmap'] for p in population])
```